# Como realizar cálculo de comissão de vendas

Tags: java, método, matemática, porcentagem

Para resumir bem o que eu quero, vou fazer de forma que o programa deve rodar:

```
Digite o nome do vendedor: Joao
Digite a meta do vendedor: 1000
Digite o valor de vendas: 499
```

Após isso preciso fazer com o que o programa entenda que se a meta for menor que 50% das vendas, o vendedor irá ganhar 1% ou seja nesse valor de exemplo deveria aparecer:

```
Seu lucro foi de 4,99.
```

Porém tens mais `else if` no caso, se meta for maior de 50 a 70%, ele lucra 2,5%, se for 75,1 a 100% lucra 3,5% e se for acima de 100% lucra 5%. Acredito que ficou claro, o que fiz de código está abaixo, nao sei como por a logica dentro dos parenteses do if.

```
public class Vendedor {
    //definindo atributos
    private String nome;
    private double meta;
    private double totalVendido;


    //criacao do metodo para calcular a comissao do vendedor
    public double calcularComissao() {
        double valorVendido;
        if (totalVendido < 0.5) {
            valorVendido = (totalVendido * 0.01);
        }else if(totalVendido ) {
            valorVendido = (totalVendido * 0.025);
        }else if(totalVendido ) {
            valorVendido = (totalVendido * 0.035);
        }else if(totalVendido ) {
            valorVendido = (totalVendido * 0.05);
        }else {
            valorVendido = 0;
        }
        return valorVendido;
   }


}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: Ta e me diz onde que não fui claro? já ta bem claro do jeito que botei, preciso que rode daquela forma e não sei o que boto dentro do if, já está dito...Precisamos de moderadores melhores

Comment: Moderadores melhores fariam o mesmo. Se quiser discutir sobre isso poste no lugar, correto, que é o site [meta]. Fique sossegado que se o problema for o moderador a própria comunidade vai reabrir seu post, todos podem votar reabertura se quiserem.

Comment: Tranquilo irei fazer mesmo, pois é só aqui no brasileiro que é dessa forma, botei no americano e já me ajudaram com a mesma pergunta, não é a toa que brasil é dessa forma mesmo, se ninguém tivesse entendido, não tinham me respondido, mas aparentemente foi só tu tens que ter mais interpretação das coisas, pois tu bota para dizer o problema, sendo que já disse "não sei o que por no if" e tentativa de solução, já botei o código, precisa mais do que? eu desenhar pra ti?

Comment: Aliás, tem um problema de interpretação de texto, em nenhum lugar foi dito que seu post não está claro. Sugiro aprimorar leitura de texto, e ler os links indicados. Lá está mais do que explicado o motivo de fechamento das suas questões (e nem vou precisar desenhar!). Conforme comentei, se quiser discutir isto, faça no local correto, link já passado anteriormente.

Comment: Certo, acho que tu ta mais precisando do que eu, o que seria objetivo e pontual? clarissimo, mais objetivo e pontual do que fui não tem, preciso que rode daquela forma e não sei fazer o if pronto,ou é só tu que gosta de ler em uma linha? Assim como muitos aqui são alunos, e são novatos, e se eu não ver lógicas não vou aprender.

Comment: E outra tu não tem que se meter, se não tinha nenhuma reclamação do meu post.

Comment: @felipitodos Você está em um lugar público onde todos podem se meter, se você não está confortável com isso faça suas perguntas em um lugar privado que ninguém se meterá. Algumas pessoas são experientes aqui e podem ajudar de formas que nem imagina, e justamente por essa experiência sabemos que nem sempre será percebido, entediemos que as pessoas querem a solução fácil ,mesmo que errada, confusa. Claramente não está aberto à uma resposta que não seja o que quer ouvir, então fica complicado

Comment: É uma obrigação que assumi como moderador. Meu papel, entre outros é garantir qualidade do conteúdo coletivo, sua pergunta na forma atual não agrega ao coletivo, então não serve para o site. Conforme convidado, pode discutir o assunto no lugar correto, e pode melhorar a postagem conforme convidado no 1º comment (com as devidas orientações). O resto é perda de um tempo precioso com coisa que não vale a pena. Para estancar o problema, os comentários desta postagem foram bloqueados. O link do local para debate sobre o site foi passado acima, fique à vontade para usar, de maneira civilizada..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

primeiro vc terá que descobrir qual a porcentagem para depois colocar no "if"

(499/1000)*100 = 49,90%
então, entra na faixa de 1%
sacou a ideia?

Comment: Certo, mas como que faço, não compreendi muito bem, seria tipo:
(Meta / totalVendido) * 100 e desse resultado eu faço o if?

Comment: @felipi Você aceitou a resposta, então você compreendeu tudo. Com boas perguntas se obtém boas respostas, quando as pessoas não respondem bem é porque a pergunta tin ha problemas. Aconteceu aqui, aconteceu no SOen. A diferença é que lá tem milhares de pots lá e a maioria não é moderada, mas a pergunta gera resposta problemáticas, quem tem experiência lê, interpreta e sabe qual será o resultado. Eu sei que é frustrante para quem pergunta, mas é mais para quem cuida do site ver postagens que geram mais confusão que informação que ajuda outras pessoas.